# Getting wrong date while converting date

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse date string into date. I have tried following code

```
public class convertDate
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String strlastruntime ="16/06/2016 9:17:00 AM",dateFormat ="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";

        try
        {
            strlastruntime = strlastruntime.trim();
            System.out.println("strlastruntime = "+strlastruntime+" dateFormat = "+dateFormat);
            java.util.Locale l = java.util.Locale.US;
            java.text.SimpleDateFormat formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat,l);
            //System.out.println("formatter = "+formatter);
            java.util.Date date = formatter.parse( strlastruntime );
            System.out.println("date = "+date);
            long time = date.getTime();
            System.out.println("time = "+time);

        }
        catch(java.text.ParseException ee)
        {
            ee.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(ee);
        }
    }
}
```

But, I am getting wrong output for the above input string
I am getting this output while running the code:

```
strlastruntime = 16/06/2016 9:17:00 AM dateFormat = MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a
date = Thu Apr 06 09:17:00 IST 2017
time = 1491450420000
```

So, please help me to find the solution..

Comment: What output did you expect instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `dateFormat ="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";`
 to `dateFormat ="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";`

full code

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String strlastruntime ="16/06/2016 9:17:00 AM",dateFormat ="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";

        try
        {
            strlastruntime = strlastruntime.trim();
            System.out.println("strlastruntime = "+strlastruntime+" dateFormat = "+dateFormat);
            java.util.Locale l = java.util.Locale.US;
            java.text.SimpleDateFormat formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat,l);
            //System.out.println("formatter = "+formatter);
            java.util.Date date = formatter.parse( strlastruntime );
            System.out.println("date = "+date);
            long time = date.getTime();
            System.out.println("time = "+time);

        }
        catch(java.text.ParseException ee)
        {
            ee.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(ee);
        }
    }
```

output:

```
strlastruntime = 16/06/2016 9:17:00 AM dateFormat = dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a
date = Thu Jun 16 09:17:00 IST 2016
time = 1466048820000
```

Comment: Hai, May I know why that date format (dateFormat ="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a") is not working in my code?

Comment: Yes, But I have one more question, Is there any option in java to know the date format for given date string for example String dt_str ="16/06/2016 9:17:00 AM"; or Is there any method to find the Date & Time format of the System. In my environment one win 2008 R2 gives the date format like "16/06/2016 9:17:00 AM" and another win 2008 R2 gives like this format "06/16/2016 9:17:00 AM". So first I need to find the date & time format to parse that string. Please tell me the solution

Comment: @KaviChinna if your problem is solved then you can accept this answer. For your new question, ask in a different thread